# Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ and assume that $f(x)|g(x)$ for every nonconstant $g(x) \in F[x]$. Show that $f(x)$ is constant

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

because $f(x)|g(x)$ $f(x)$ must share at least one root with $g(x)$ and because $g(x)$ could be any degree polynomial that don't share the same roots (ex: $x+1$, $x-2$) $f(x)$ must be a constant value. Do I have the right idea with this one?

Comment: Note that not every polynomial in $F[x]$ has roots in $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is not sufficient as $F$ need not be algebraically closed. For example $X^2+1\in\mathbb R[X]$ or $X^2-2\in\mathbb Q[X]$ have no roots but are not constant.

But if we know that $f|X$ and $f|X+1$, then also $f|(X+1)-X=1$, which implies $\deg f\le\deg 1=0$.

Comment: great answer! Thanks!